# How to install mysql 5.6 on debian 6.0.10 squeeze?

Tags: debian

Currently on the server

$ cat /etc/debian_version
6.0.10
$ dpkg -l | grep mysql

But I need to install mysql 5.6 packages.
I looked at the official page

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/

but it does not provide a mysql-ap-config package for debian 6 (the earliest one I found is mysql-apt-config_0.3.7-1debian7_all.deb)
Can I compile it from sources or is there a an apt-get config that will allow me to install mysql 5.6?

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Hi Really simple as root if you dont have sudo installed

apt-get update && apt-get install mysql-server

This is the debian package

https://packages.debian.org/squeeze/database/mysql-server

Ups sorry you ment version 5.6 Take a look at this post

https://serverfault.com/questions/22414/how-can-i-run-debian-stable-but-install-some-packages-from-testing

since that package is on the testing branch

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install mysql-5.6.26 by downloading the Oracle binary:

```
wget http://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/MySQL-5.6/mysql-5.6.26-debian6.0-x86_64.deb
sudo dpkg -i mysql-5.6.26-debian6.0-x86_64.deb
```

Note: this will install mysql files to /opt/mysql/server-5.6/ folder which means that if you want to be able to use

```
service mysql restart
```

you will have to edit the /etc/init.d/mysql script (if you have it) and replace references to /usr/bin/mysql* with their /opt/mysql/server-5.6/bin equivalents.